# Term for people that think the minority or farfetched view is always the truth?

Tags: meaning, terminology

Not just limited to conspiracy theorists, but folks who have a tendency to believe in alternative, super minority views as THE truth and strongly believe in them with little validation or proof. They also have a dislike for consensus views (because it's too "easy"), and believe that populace is being manipulated and are too naive or complacent to see the real truth.

Comment: Is this a positive term or a negative one?

Comment: ***Irrational.***

Comment: I really wish there were a word for it.

Answer (score 3):

Contrarian is a possibility, although it doesn't imply the aspect of having little evidence for beliefs. Contrarian definitely has a more positive spin.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is ***credulous***; an adjective, which Oxford Dictionaries Online defines as *having or showing too great a readiness to believe things.*

The OED (sense 2) makes clear that its modern use indicates a willingness to believe on shallow grounds:

> 2. Too ready or willing to believe; inclined to believe on weak or insufficient grounds. (Now the usual sense.)
>
> Recent examples:
>
> 1961   L. Mumford City in Hist. xvii. 546   A world of professional
>   illusionists and their credulous victims.
>
> 2007   Time Out N.Y. 11 Oct. 168/2   A little girl manages to hoax a
>   credulous nation into believing in fairies in this..story.

Comment: But in the case posed the credulousness is selective, excluding the more widely believed explanations. It has a bias to it, which one might call a *contrarian* bias.

Comment: According to the OED, the nowadays more common meaning is:*Too ready or willing to believe; inclined to believe on weak or insufficient grounds.(Now the usual sense.)* I am going to add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A person who exhibits those traits might identify themselves as a **skeptic**.

> a person who questions the validity or authenticity of something purporting to be factual.

[dictionary.com/browse/skeptic (1.)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/skeptic)

Examples of the term **skeptic** being adopted by groups interested in considering the fringe/uncommon:

[Reddit: r/skeptic](https://www.reddit.com/r/skeptic/)

[Magazine: The Skeptic Society](http://www.skeptic.com/)

But if you are looking to attach a more negative connotation to this personality type **skeptic** is probably not the right word.

Answer (score 0):

## [Nonconformist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nonconformist)

> a person who refuses to conform, as to established customs, attitudes, or ideas.

## [Individualist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/individualist)

> a person who shows great independence or individuality in thought or action.

#### [Divergent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divergent)

> 1. diverging from each other
>    *"divergent paths"*
> 2. differing from each other or from a standard
>    *"the divergent interests of capital and labor"*

#### [Disparate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disparate)

> 1. containing or made up of fundamentally different and often [incongruous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incongruous) elements
> 2. markedly distinct in quality or character

#### [Incongruous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incongruous)

> strange because of not agreeing with what is usual or expected
> *"His outburst seemed incongruous to those who know him well."*